# Regular expression for blood pressure

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression to validate blood pressure values in the form of systolic/diastolic:

`\b[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,3}\b`

The expression works with the only flaw that it allows more than one non-consecutive slash (/). For example, it allows this `2/2/2`. I want it to allow only the format of a number from 1 to 999, and slash, and again a number from 1 to 999. For example, 83/23, 1/123, 999/999, 110/80, etc. Can anybody give me some help with this?

The only other expression I've found [is here](http://regexlib.com/%28A%28vN9p5isH7AWDW5_So2QPyMryVsydhnd82vLVCzR1nXmqlxshgWRqJSpLyy71BExWfuANSrQdw3ByLaoFlaLNxZBsWxljvE-JekHUftKQ2eC-MD4nfS2PFZUD5YfFIIad6c59TfkC2-oK02pycT8IloxKRWH99tKVq8Ucjn4c3E8YcuKF2oSmX2HGKJaL39fA0%29%29/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2769&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1): `^\b(29[0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\/(29[0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should use anchors at both ends. `Caret(^)` and `Dollar($)`.

Comment: How are you using that regex? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Rohit: if the blood pressure was the *whole* of the string, required if it's to match the `^` and `$` (unless I'm misunderstanding something, which is possible since I'm still relatively new to RegEx), there'd be no point using RegEx to match it.

Comment: jQuery makes no difference. This is intended for use with *Javascript*. Also, why Regex at all? Split on `/` and test for array length and if valid at two, if both are between 1-999.

Comment: @RohitJain got it right, you should post an answer.. and the \b boundaries are unecessary when using the carets ^ and $

Comment: @RohitJain, I'm using the jquery validation plugin with a pattern to validate the value of a textbox

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the string:

```
^\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}$
```

By doing so, you force the matched strings to be *exactly* of that form.

Comment: Nit: This would still accept `0/999`, which is technically invalid .. not to mention all sort of nonsensical values. Sometimes a regular expression is only part of what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `\b` word-boundaries because a slash counts as a word boundary.

The use of `^` and/or `$` is likely your most simple solution. Unfortunately, if your input is a part of a string or sentence or occurs more than once in a line, etc., you've got more thinking to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\b(29[0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/(29[0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

This is correct, the other had one extra \

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Blender's answer, here is a simple check for validating BP value in the format: 120/80:

```
if(/^\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}$/.test(120/80)) {
    console.log("BP Valid");
} else {
    console.log("Invalid BP");
}
```